# Debo mover los datos de un JCombobox a otro JCombobox con un botón, pero al darle al botón marca error o se congela la ventana de la aplicación

Tags: java

```
        MoverTodMayAMen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int i=0;
                for(i=0;i<=i;i++) { 
                    menores.addItem(mayores.getSelectedItem());
                    mayores.setSelectedIndex(i);
                }
                mayores.removeAllItems();
            }
        });
```

Con el código así marca error y lo que hace es mandar el primer dato del combobox dos veces y los demás una, pero sigue marcando error. Y usando mayores.getSelectedItem(); se congela la aplicación.

Comment: ¿qué error te marca el código? Nos muestras muy poco, ¿cómo y donde se definen *mayores* y *menores*, por ejemplo?